# C++11 compiler confused between class and a same-named class method

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a class:

```
class Feedback
: public Message
{
  // Do some stuff
};
```

And somewhere else, I have a handler class:

```
class EpisodicHandler
{

  void Feedback ( ) {}

};
```

Now, in another class, I am trying:

```
if ( std::shared_ptr<Feedback> feedback = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<Feedback>( message ) )
...
```

For 15 minutes, all I could get out of the compiler was:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘dynamic_pointer_cast(std::shared_ptr<Message>&)’
```

Where Message is the abstract base class:

```
class Message
{
  public:

    virtual void setRaw( const std::string ) = 0;

    virtual std::string Bytes( void ) const = 0;

    virtual bool store( void ) = 0;

    virtual ~Message( ){ };

};
```

Shuffling some if-elses around, I managed to get the compiler to print:

```
error:   expected a type, got ‘EpisodicHandler::Feedback’
error: no matching function for call to ‘dynamic_pointer_cast(std::shared_ptr<Message>&)’
  else if ( std::shared_ptr<Feedback> feedback = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<Feedback>( message ) )
```

Which seems bizzare to me, as I am not specifying EpisodicHandler::Feedback!
The method is visible through inheritance from another imported class.

Other than renaming the class or the method, is there a way to explicitly specify that I mean the class and not the method "Feedback" ?

Thank you!

PS: compiler is gcc (Debian 4.8.2-1) 4.8.2

Comment: Can you give some more information, i.e. what is the `message` object look like, so the problem can be reproduced?

Comment: @XiaogeSu Hi! I've added the ABC Message. There is nothing really complicated, its just an ABC from which many classes inherit. When trying to downcast them, it works fine, except for Feedback, because the compiler seems unable to differentiate between class Feedback, and EpisodicHandler::Feedback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the namespace:

```
if ( std::shared_ptr<::Feedback> feedback = ...
```

That way it will know to select the class. The function of the same name is inside the other class so you'd have an object to access it. But if you are programming with the second class you'd have that problem, indeed.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I'm afraid that even with the name space it still has problems, but you just told me why, because the class where the if-else statements are, inherits from the class that inherits from EpisodicHandler. Thanks a lot !!